# Redirecting URL using HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, http-redirect

Im trying to direct the following URL https://register.company.xzy to https://register.company.xzy/register/supplier?code=

My haproxy config has acls in it for some existing subdomains and has been working well but i cant see to get this to work:

```
frontend https
    bind 10.10.2.150:443 ssl crt /etc/apache2/ssl/star.company.xyz.pem
    mode http
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    acl www.company.xyz hdr(host) -i www.company.xyz
    acl portal.company.xyz hdr(host) -i portal.company.xyz
    acl live.company.xyz hdr(host) -i live.company.xyz
    acl register.company.xyz hdr(host) -i register.company.xyz

    use_backend website_live_servers if www.company.xyz
    use_backend website_live_servers if portal.company.xyz
    use_backend application_live_servers if live.company.xyz
    use_backend register_live_servers  if register.company.xyz

backend application_live_servers
    mode http
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server server1 server1.company.xyz:80 check cookie $1

backend register_live_servers
    mode http
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server server2 server2.company.xyz:80 check cookie $1

backend website_live_servers
    mode http
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server server3 server3.company.xyz:80 check cookie $1
    server server3 server3.company.xyz:80 check cookie $2
```

Any ideas or guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Well what you need is to rewrite URL

```
http-request set-path <fmt> [<condition>]
http-request set-query <fmt> [<condition>]
```

OR rewrite complete URI

```
http-request set-uri <fmt> [<condition>]
```

[rewriting url path](https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/http_rewriting.html#rewriting-http-urls)